# PyQt Release vs Debug

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, cx-freeze

I have a system,written on PyQt4. It is mostly developed and debug under linux (ubuntu) systems, in Eric IDE, and everything works fine. Last task was to create a nested editor for a table cell. So, i did it and it also looks nice in ubuntu. I also ran it under Windows 7 x64, and the behavior was the same.

However, after making executable file with cx_Freeze in Windows 2000 (it's weird, but this environment was configured before me), the editors behavior became unexpected. After opening Editor it's first cell have 'role == Qt.EditRole', and it's almost impossible to commit any changes there without closing the whole Editor. Another issue is about "OK" button - it closes the Editor window, but doesn't commit any changes in it also, and you cannot call it again without changing the active cell (but maybe i just forgot to emit some signals here, so it's not the main bug here).

So my question - where should i look to find the reason for these problems. I'm new to qt, and maybe it is normal behavior and just my fault in code? Or the reason is in different environments (python 2.7, latest pyqt vs python 2.6 and some older pyqt). Or it is the influence of cx_Freeze... Maybe some other directions?

Sorry for long post and my English :)
Hope to get any answers soon.

Comment: It's possible cx_Freeze isn't copying all of the files it needs to, which is making your code do something different. If you have an old version of cx_Freeze, try updating it. Also, try freezing on Ubuntu, and see if you get the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a chance that Qt or PyQt on windows 2000 server is outdated or broken.

So If possible, bring cx_freeze related code to your local computer and test it out.

If it fixes the problem, you can upgrade or reinstall Qt on windows 2000 server.